# In Lumen, how do I change the method to be called on a route's controller during middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, lumen

I like Laravel, but I don't like ORM's and I want more speed...so I use Lumen. However, porting my code over to Lumen I discovered some changes in what I can do with the middleware...

I like to use middleware to make my ajax requests more "restful" by changing the controller method that will be called based on the request. Here's what I did in Laravel 5:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->ajax() && $request->input("ajax")){

       // Controller methods like: ajaxEdit, ajaxUpdate, ajaxDelete...
       $ajaxMethod = "ajax".studly_case($request->input("ajax"));

       // Get the route's action
       $routeAction = $request->route()->getAction();

       // Replace index method call with ajax method
       $routeAction['uses'] = str_replace("@index", "@".$ajaxMethod, $routeAction['uses']);
       $routeAction['controller'] = str_replace("@index", "@".$ajaxMethod, $routeAction['controller']);

       // Update the route's action
       $request->route()->setAction($routeAction);
    }

    // Now controller->ajaxWhatever will be called instead of controller->index
    return $next($request);
}
```

I noticed `getAction` and `setAction` are not available in Lumen. How could I accomplish something similar in Lumen?

Comment: Lumen uses https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute, so I'd start digging there.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think it's going to involve updating laravel's request somehow. There's nothing in FastRoute at this point in the request lifecycle that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now (as this feature seems to be [on the road map to being added](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/63)), I just handled this at the top of my routes file:

*routes.php*

```
// ***** Pre-routing logic

// Convert all ajax calls with a request parameter "ajax" 
// to a corresponding controller's ajax method.
// For example, if request parameter "?ajax=edit" then 
// call method SomeController@ajaxEdit.
$indexAjax = "index";
$request = $app['request'];
if($request->ajax() && $request->input("ajax")){
    $indexAjax = "ajax".studly_case($request->input("ajax"));
}


// ***** Routes

$app->group(['namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel', 'prefix'=>'admin'], function($app) use ($indexAjax)
{
    $app->get('login/', ['as' => 'admin-login', 'uses' => 'Login\LoginController@'.$indexAjax]);
});

$app->group(['namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel', 'middleware'=>['auth'], 'prefix'=>'admin'], function($app) use ($indexAjax)
{
    $app->get('users/', ['as' => 'admin-users', 'uses' => 'Admin\UsersController@'.$indexAjax]);
    $app->get('logout/', ['as' => 'admin-logout', 'uses' => 'Login\LoginController@logout']);
});
```